# mySQL / Python Problems

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

I am a new A-Level student, doing AS computer science.
I really don't know how to fix this problem but I need help with the following code.
I am trying to incorporate mySQL into Python and query data successfully. I also am trying to update a certain table via python. I am running into problems however that seem to throw errors that aren't actually happening as far as I can see. Am I blind? I hope that you geniuses can help me work it out.

The problem I have is that the SQL query I try to execute does not work and throws the following error (if the name I enter is 'Harvey', for example):

> raise errors.get_exception(packet)
> mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'Harvey' in 'field list'

#Here is the actual code. It's trying to update a table record for name, DOB, and city by sorting via a unique 'key_field' identifier.

```
  if int(key) < 1 or int(key) > len(ages):
  print("The Key Field Number you entered is out of range of the data we have. Try again.")
  continue
  else:
  n = input("""
  Enter the name for the new record: """)
  if len(n) > 50:
      print("The name you entered is too long, try again.")
      continue
  
  c = input("""
  Enter the name of the city for the new record: """)
  if len(c) > 30:
      print("The city you entered is too long. Try again.")
      continue
  
  dob_year = input("""
  Entering the DOB (Date of Birth) for the new record... 
  Enter the year (YYYY): """)
  if len(dob_year) != 4:
      print("The year you enter must be 4 numbers long. Try again.")
      continue
  
  dob_month = input("Enter the month (MM): ")
  if len(dob_month) > 2 or len(dob_month) < 1:
      print("The month you enter must be 2 numbers long. Try again.")
      continue
  
  if len(dob_month) == 1:
      dob_month = "0" + dob_month
  
  dob_day = input("Enter the day (DD): ")
  if len(dob_day) > 2 or len(dob_day) < 1:
      print("The day you enter must be 2 numbers long. Try again.")
      continue
  
  if len(dob_day) == 1:
      dob_day = "0" + dob_day
  
  try:
      int(dob_day)
      int(dob_month)
      int(dob_year)
  
  except:
      print("Enter integer values for the DOB (Date of Birth) section. Try again.")
      continue
  
  else:
      d = "%s-%s-%s" % (dob_year, dob_month, dob_day)
  
      ndc = []
      ndc.append(n)
      ndc.append(d)
      ndc.append(c)
      ndc = tuple(ndc)
      key = int(key)
  
  sql = "UPDATE ppl SET name = %s, dob = %s, city = %s WHERE key_field = %s" % (ndc[0], ndc[1], ndc[2], key)
  mycursor.execute(sql)
  mydb.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are building a string with  out the proper single quotes that mysql needs t identify strings, so it takes them as colum nnames, but you should use the prepared statements that you already have

```
 sql = "UPDATE ppl SET name = %s, dob = %s, city = %s WHERE key_field = %s" 
 mycursor.execute(sql,(ndc[0], ndc[1], ndc[2], key))
 mydb.commit()
```

Comment: Thank you so much man, I would not have ever seen that tiny thing, the code works now uve saved me a lot of frustration bro